# how do I call this method with list as an argument from another class?

Tags: apex, list, compile-error

Below is the name of my method and argument of that method

```
private static void Callout(List<Id>cnt)
```

I am calling above method using following code

```
classname.Callout(cnt.id). //where cnt is contact cnt = new contact(LastName='test');
```

I am getting this error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: class.Callout(Id)

Can you advice how else can I call that method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to construct a `List` which contains a single element, you can use curly brackets (`{}`):

```
ClassName.callout(new List<Id> { cnt.Id });
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian. I have tried above solution. still getting another error. Error now tells method is not visible classname.callout(List<Id>)

Comment: @Aman You can only call `public` methods... You could change the method declaration's access modifier from `private` to `public`.

Answer (score 3):

You should keep some other things in mind as well like:

You should use naming conventions in your code like use `camelCase` for method names and variable names and `CamelCase` for class name

```
class ClassName{
    private static void callout(List<Id> cnt){
        /* Method logic here */
    }
}
```

Rest is covered by @Adrian in the [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/173779/29734).